# Google таблицы. Работа с временем

Tags: время, google-spreadsheet

Задача: Прибавить 9 часов к настоящему времени и после этого сравнивать настоящее время с будущим. Если настоящее время больше то какое то действие.

В общем я много чего накопал, но вот корректно работать со временем не получается. Хочу манипулировать временем в сценарии, но не могу найти инфу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего должно работать так:

```
= NOW() + 9/24
```

Если речь про javascript, то:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours() + 9);
```

Comment: 1. А что я прибавил? 2. На каком языке сценарий? Разве не на js?

Comment: Да, все правильно. Только как вот через код с датой работать ? А за этот пример тоже спасибо.

Comment: `var d = new Date(); d.setHours(d.getHours() + 9);` - ну в js так.

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем